# Google Cloud Storage Bucket: XML error when reloading an Ember.js app in GCS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-platform

We recently moved an Ember.js app hosted in an Amazon AWS S3 bucket to a Google Cloud Storage Bucket. The app works great when we load the index.html page. Ember transitions work just fine however, when we directly visit a URL that isn't the project's main route (for example, `/account-settings`) or reload a URL that we are working on, we get the following error:

```
<Error>
    <Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
    <Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
</Error>
```

My assumption is that this has to do with the request not being handled by the Ember Router and index.html? Is there any way to tell Google Cloud Storage to redirect all requests to index.html so that the Ember Router can handle it? I couldn't find any solutions to fix this in the Google Cloud documentation. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to fix this by setting the error page of my Google Cloud Storage bucket to `index.html`.